# Command "grep | cut" in shell programming

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

I have a problem with the `grep` command.

I have a file, called *dictionary.txt*, containing 2 columns of words, like

```
abc def
apple orange
hour minute
```

In my Bash script, having entered the word in the left column as an argument, I have to output the corresponding word on the right using the `grep` command.

A **requirement** is to use a loop.

I created this script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

parola=$1

for traduzione in $( sort dictionary.txt )
do
     if [ $parola == $traduzione ]
     then
     grep $traduzione | cut -f 2 dictionary.txt
     fi
done
```

This does not work as described above.

Comment: There are numerous _potential_ issues in your script (more than I can fit in a comment), but you haven’t told us what, _exactly_, you’re having trouble with, so it’s hard to answer.

Comment: `grep | cut` is almost always better spelled `awk`

Comment: Tangentially, [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), and [quote your variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable).

Comment: The specific problem with `cut` is that it expects tab-delimited input, not space-delimited.

Comment: Sorting the file seems completely superfluous here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to replace the whole `for` loop with

```sh
awk -v word="$parola" '$1 == word{print $2;exit}' dictionary.txt
```

where

- `-v word="$parola"` passes the `parola` variable to the awk script
- `$1 == word` checks if the Column 1 value equals the `parola`
- `{print $2;exit}` - prints the Column2 value and exits (remove `exit` if you need all matches on the further lines).

With `dictionary.txt` as

```
abc def
apple orange
hour minute
```

and `script.sh` as

```
#!/bin/bash
parola=$1
awk -v word="$parola" '$1 == word{print $2; exit}' dictionary.txt
```

the `bash script.sh apple` returns `orange`.

If you need a `for` loop you can use

```sh
#!/bin/bash
parola=$1

while IFS= read -a line; do
  read -r left right <<< "$line"
  if [ "$left" == "$parola" ]; then
     echo "$right";
  fi
done < dictionary.txt
```

That is:

- Read `dictionary.txt` line by line assigning the current line value to the `line` variable
- Read the values on a line into `left` and `right` variables
- If `left` is equal to `right`, print `right`.

Comment: Apparently, you were entering your answer at the moment I was typing mine, but I admit, yours is more complete than mine :-)

Comment: thanks, but what if i want to do it with a for?

Comment: @AlessioScalzo I added another variation with a loop.

Comment: @AlessioScalzo  You don't want to use a for loop for this. You just want `sort dictionary.txt | awk ...`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a `for`-loop?

```
grep -w "word1" dictionary.txt
```

This shows you the line where you can find that word, so the `for`-loop is not even needed. For your information, `-w` means "only take whole words".

Comment: I have to use the for because I have a specific request to use the for :-)

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, you accepted, there are two possibilities: either you use a `for`-loop, read line by line, and parse that line, or you use `grep` for finding the exact line you are looking for. It makes no sense (at least in this situation) to combine `for` and `grep`.